# Interpreting results of profiled php code

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I finally got [xdebug](http://xdebug.com/) set up and running and I'm using [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) to understand the data.

Can someone explain how to understand the data? There's just a bunch of terms that I'm not sure of, like: Invocation Count, Total Self Cost, Total Inclusive Cost. I also don't understand what changing the "show percentage" does. (It defaults to 90%). Any tips on how to use webgrind to understand my php application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are some personal definitions:

Invocation Count:

the number of times a given method or function has been called

Total Inclusive Cost:

total time or percentage of time spend in a given method or function

Total Self Cost:

Total Inclusive Cost of a function or method  minus Total Inclusive Cost of the methods or functions that are called inside